# How can I deploy a React App inside a subdirectory on the server?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, .htaccess, ecmascript-6, react-router

No tutorial from React and other websites has worked to solve this problem. I have my router like this:

```
<Router basename={'/doncarro'}>
   <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard}></Route>
        <Route exact path="/campaigns" component={Campaigns}></Route>
        <Route exact path="/leads" component={Leads}></Route>
        <Route exact path="/admin" component={Admin}></Route>
        <Route exact path="/admin/users" component={AdminUsers}></Route>
        <Route exact path="/admin/users/:id" component={AdminUserInfo}></Route>
        <Route exact path="/admin/users/:id/edit" component={AdminUserEdit}></Route>
        <Route exact path="/user" component={User}></Route>
        <Route exact path="/logout" component={Logout}></Route>
        <Redirect exact from="/" to="/dashboard" />
        <Route path="*" component={NotFound} status={404}></Route>
    </Switch>
</Router>
```

So basically I just want my app to be inside https://funnel.garritz.com/doncarro/ (not working). I have already set my package.json with the `"homepage": "https://funnel.garritz.com/doncarro"` setting. So when I do the build, and I deploy inside https://funnel.garritz.com/doncarro, It just doesn't work. If I go only to the domain (without the subdirectory) it does nothing. If I try to go to https://funnel.garritz.com/doncarro, it tries to load everything, but it only gets the 404 Error.

I tried with a lot of .htaccess configurations, different forms of "build", different deployment, for example, index.html on root and all files inside /doncarro/.

### Edit

So I've been playing with the code, and the router is as follows:

```
<Router basename={'/doncarro'}>
    <Switch>
        <Route exact path={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/dashboard`} component={Dashboard}></Route>
        <Route exact path={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/campaigns`} component={Campaigns}></Route>
        <Route exact path={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/leads`} component={Leads}></Route>
        <Route exact path={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/admin`} component={Admin}></Route>
        <Route exact path={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/admin/users`} component={AdminUsers}></Route>
        <Route exact path={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/admin/users/:id`} component={AdminUserInfo}></Route>
        <Route exact path={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/admin/users/:id/edit`} component={AdminUserEdit}></Route>
        <Route exact path={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/user`} component={User}></Route>
        <Route exact path={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/logout`} component={Logout}></Route>
        <Redirect exact from={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/`} to={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/dashboard`} />
        <Route component={NotFound} status={404}></Route>
    </Switch>
</Router>
```

The funny thing is that if I remove the `basename={'/doncarro'}` everything works just fine, so I don't see the point of the feature. Also, I've put the .htaccess like this:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.html [QSA,L]
```

What am I doing wrong? I don't really know what is happening.

Comment: Can you show your webpack config files? And what is the current folder structure that you use on the server? (I don't see any 404s in the devtools Network tab at the moment)

Comment: Hi! I am not using webpack. Anyway, it is just a folder inside the server, so public_html -> doncarro -> and I am deploying here.

Comment: @PabloZehle..can you share the solution for this issue. How you get this thing resolved.  I am facing same issue. I am not able to deploy react app under a virtual directory.
One more question if you can answer. How to host the webapi under the same virtual directory and how to call that api from react app. I googled a lot but didnt found a statisfactory answer

Comment: @Developer, you need to simply add `basename={'/yoursubdirectory'}` to your router declaration (like in the edit above). But also the key is to add `"homepage": "https://myapp.com/directory-name"` to your package.json. If you created a create-react-app, it contains already a nice .htaccess file for this to work. As for the API that needs to be handled by your virtual hosts and server configuration.

Comment: @PabloZehle..thanks for you suggestion. I had made changes suggested by you but still facing the same issue. When i debug that on chrome i found it is still trying to access some static files which are not there. How to remove refrence or cache of these files(chunk.js)?I think because of this page is still not loading

Comment: @Developer are you having this issue while running on localhost? Or after performing `npm run build`?

Comment: @PabloZehle..thanks for your help..issue got resolved by the solution you gave. I missed to change reference for one of the pages where i want to redirect.Thanks